# Proof of Prime Number Relation for Polynomial With Integer Coefficients that is a factor of the Asymptotic Expasion of the Gamma Function

Tags: number-theory

I would like to prove (or disprove) the following assertions made regarding the Gamma function:

$$\lim _{z\rightarrow w}\Biggl(\frac{\mathcal A_{k} \left( \Gamma  \left( z \right) \right)
                   (3(1-\delta(k,1))+1)
z^{k}(\frac{1}{z})^{z}\operatorname{e}^{z}}{\sqrt {\frac{2\pi}{z}}}\Biggr)=\mathcal P_{k}(w)=\sum _{j=0}^{k}\alpha_{{j,k}}{w}^{j} \quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(0)$$
Where:

$\alpha_{{j,k}} \in \mathbb Z$

$\mathcal A_{k} \left( f\left( z \right) \right)$ is the asymptotic expansion of $f(z)$ computed to $k$ terms

$\delta \left( x,y \right) =\cases{1&$x=y$\cr 0&$x\neq y$\cr}$

In trying to deepen my understanding of the Gamma function and it's relationship with the prime numbers, I made a few conjectures based on the patterns I had observed aside from what I have already stated regarding (0).

As I have stated,polynomial $\mathcal P_{k}(z)$, that appears as a factor of the asymptotic expansion of the gamma function, (where k is the number of terms the expansion was computed)has integer coefficients, and the sum of these coefficients always has a maximum integer factor that is prime, i.e in it's unique prime factorization product, the largest term always has a multiplicity of 1:

$$\max\Biggl( \mathcal F\Bigl(\sum _{j=0}^{k}\alpha_{{j,k}}\Bigr)\Biggr) \in \mathbb P\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,\,(1)$$
where $\mathcal F(N)$ a set  whose elements are the terms of the unique factorization product of $N$.
Furthermore, the set of coefficients for $\mathcal P_{k+1}(z)$ and the set of coefficients of $\mathcal P_{k}(z)$ are disjoint, or in general we have:

For $ \mathbb A_{k}={\{\alpha_{{j,k}}}\}_{j=0..k}$ :

$$\mathbb A_{k_i} \cap\mathbb A_{k_j} ={\{\,}\}\,\,\, \forall k_i,k_j \in \mathbb N\,\,\,\operatorname{s.t}\,\, k_i \neq k_j\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2)$$

Regarding the first assertion, for the first 1000 natural numbers, roughly just over 84 percent of them have largest factors that are prime, and the remaining 16 percent are composite. Of the first $10^6$ natural numbers, 96 percent have prime maximum factors. I find it therefore worthy of observation that these values defined in (1) are *always* prime.

But the percentage of numbers less than or equal to $n$ having a prime maximum factor asymptotically will approach 100 percent, this presenting us with a bit of a paradox, seeing we know already there exist numbers with composite maximum factors, making it impossible for this value to ever truly be reached!

[image]

As an additional side note,$k=1$ has as a  $\alpha_{k}$ set equal to the empty product, and the corresponding polynomial is $\mathcal P_1(z)=z$,which implies the empty product is equal to unity, ie this result gives credence to  propositions that non numerical objects in fact are natural numbers computationally speaking:

$${\{\{\,\,}\}\}=1\in \mathbb N\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(3)$$

Comment: When you say "asymptotic expansion" could you clarify how it's calculated? Is it a taylor series? What point is it expanded around? etc.

Comment: First the reciprocal is substituted ie we  substitute $z$ for $\frac{1}{z}$ then compute the Taylor series for that expression

Comment: Then we perform the same substitution again, returning us back to $z$, substituting $z$ for $\frac{1}{z}$ into the Taylor series

Comment: This was expanded around $z=0$.

Comment: ${\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }\sqrt {{z}^{-1}}}{ \left( {z}^{-1}
 \right) ^{z}{{\rm e}^{z}}}}+\frac{1}{12}\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }
 \left( {z}^{-1} \right) ^{3/2}}{ \left( {z}^{-1} \right) ^{z}{{\rm e}
^{z}}}}
$ is the series taken for truncation order of k=2, or two monomial terms as far as I have interpreted the definition

Comment: Would I help if I added a table of evaluations for the first 10 computed? Obviously I'm not entirely comfortable with $k$ being a variable here, because it's arbitrarily chosen by the person performing the computation as to what number of terms the finite series we are using to approximate to an infinite series, I think this might be why I have never seen it done before. But still would really like to know explicitly why the coefficients are always integer

Comment: and for each truncation order, the set of such integer coefficients is unique to those of all other orders, so collectively forming a partition of disjoint subsets of $\mathbb Z$